Is it more gas efficient to delete a mappping if it maps to a bool instead of setting it to false?
Consider a mapping of some wallet addresses to a bool to check if they are whitelisted:
mapping(address => bool) wallets;

Is it more gas efficient to delete the mapping when a wallet is not approved anymore or to set the address to false, if you want to handle this in one function?
function allow(address addr, bool approved) public {
  if(approved) {
    wallets[addr] = true;
  }else {
    delete wallets[addr];
  }
}

or:
function allow(address addr, bool approved) public {
  wallets[addr] = approved;
}

As I understand setting a value costs 5,000 gas but deleting a data also refunds 15,000 gas.
What is the standard way to deal with this?

delete wallets[addr]; and wallets[addr] = false; are the same.
You will get the same gas refund either way. So.. choose the second code block as it's more succinct.
In the mapping storage, only true values are stored; everything else is considered false. This is the some for numbers. Zero values are not stored by nodes as that is the default, only non-zero values.
